# Cleaning up old reports!

Tags: reporting

I would like to clean up old reports on an annual basis. Is there a way to move old reports to a separate folder where after 30 days I would go and do a mass delete?

Comment: What are your criteria for an old report? A report that hasn't been run over a number of days?

Comment: A report that has not been run for a year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query for this information in `Apex`, and you could send out an email alert via a scheduled job for reports that have gotten stale. Here is the `SOQL` you would need to find anything that hasn't been run in the last 30 days:

```
SELECT Name, FolderName FROM Report WHERE LastRunDate < LAST_N_DAYS:30
```

If you want to change the folder or delete anything via `Apex`, you will need to use the [Metadata API](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi).